# Automated deployment of web site

Tags: deployment, web-deployment, msdeploy

I'm planning to do an automated deployment of a website,but im kind of stuck at this moment. I have looked at MS-Deploy, it got all the functions for deploying Website. I have a created a Web application package (.ZIP file) and I tested this on my local machine it is deploying website i.e

1. Create Web application under default website
2. Publishing files in c:\inetpub\wwwroot directory
3. Set ACLs on directories,etc

But i want to achieve few more extra steps for example:

1. Check whether Web application exists in Default Website, if not
   create a Web application
2. Check whether Application pool exists, if not create a App pool
   (given name) with a specific credentials and Assign App-pool to  Web
   application
3. Before it deploys take a backup copy of existing Web application (IF
   exists)
4. publish offline page (app_offline.htm)
5. publishing the files to application directory
6. Replace the AppSettings section(in web.config file) to with actual values
7. Encrypt Web.config connection string

If there is any error whilst installing web application, rollback the web application to its previous version

The question is whether can i achieve all these functions via MS-Deploy or do i need to write any script, please suggest me what scripting language should i use

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this topic but have been doing a bit of research on automated deployment with MSDeploy lately, and think I can offer the following;

1. This is default behaviour if you use the [iisApp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569054%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) provider.
2. I know you can do this with the [appPoolConfig](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569070%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) provider, but I'm unsure as to how you would run this and #1 together as part of the same package. Perhaps as part of a pre- or post-sync command?
3. This is standard in v3, as long as it's set up on the server. Not used it myself, but [read this](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-automatic-backups) anyway.
4. Fiddly. Not supported in MSDeploy, but [you can vote for it](http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41199-general/suggestions/2499911-take-my-site-app-offline-during-publishing) if you want. Also, [check out this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059109/app-offline-in-msbuild-remote-web-deploy) (and also worth checking out [PackageWeb](http://nuget.org/packages/packageweb), but the same answers' author).
5. Not sure I follow. This is done as part of a successful deployment, surely?
6. Use web.config transforms and optionally the aforementioned [PackageWeb](http://nuget.org/packages/packageweb) for a neat way to do this. Also check out `Web Publish Profiles`.
7. Difficult. My understanding is that the encryption is based on the machine.config, so you'd either have to run a post-sync script which would run some sort of remote Powershell script on the remote server to encrypt the web.config using `aspnet_regiis`, or you'd have to encrypt the config as part of your build process and then muck about with custom keys and the RSA provider ([some info here](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68ze1hb2)).

I hope that helps. As I said, I'm no expert, so happy to be corrected by those more knowledgeable. Maybe also worth mentioning that MSDeploy is a lot more powerful if you use it via the command-line rather than creating packages from VS, although there is a bit of a learning curve to go with it.