# How to custom app_offline.htm file generated by VS2019 v16

Tags: visual-studio-2019, iis-8.5

When I publish with VS, an app_offline.htm file is generated on my IIS website root folder. There is a way to custom this last please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom app\_offline.htm file during publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846097/custom-app-offline-htm-file-during-publish)

Comment: I already tryed every solutions posted on this one nothing worked but they are all about a very old VS version .. That's why I try to create a more recent one about lastest VS versions.

Answer (score 1):

In previous versions this was only changeable by tracking down the file in the VS installation.

I've not seen anything to suggest this has changed in 2019.

Comment: In my current version of VS there is no more App_Offline file in VS installation folder.

Comment: Not here either! There has certainly never been an official way to customise, and with the emphasis on CI/CD these days rather than tools in the IDE it seems unlikely there will be much priority on VS's publish tooling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid we can no longer customize VS app_offline template any more. But I think you can create a custom app_offline.htm in the root folder of your project. Then You only have to specify the operation to this file in your web deploy publish profile.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/taking-web-applications-offline-with-web-deploy

[Is there a way to make the VS2010 publish wizard to copy App_offline.htm while it is publishing the site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630428/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-vs2010-publish-wizard-to-copy-app-offline-htm-while-i)